# JSFiddle like site for classic ASP (VBScript)?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Is there something like an JSFiddle like site for classic ASP (VBScript) ?

Comment: It would be cool but I'm not sure such a tool exists and trying to tie it down to stop misuse would be a challenge. Also the fact Classic ASP is ancient I'm not sure anyone would spend the time developing something like this.

Comment: Yeah... I completely agree with you. The case is that I have to maintain a legacy application that is production only. I haven't got any local developement environment because I use Linux, and the only folder I have access copies things to production every 10 mins. So, If I just want to check syntax, I have to wait 10 mins. One error, other 10mins... check if code worked... other 10mins... I mean... this is a serial killer school... LOL

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira: Oy. That sounds... unworkable. I'd try to look into virtual machines with some sort of Windows server installed. Either that, or tell your employer that the present setup doesn't work (which is true), and that at minimum you require access to the actual production server. (It *is* possible to develop on a production server. Not ideal, certainly, but better than a 10-minute lag.)

Comment: Actually I have already finished the system that will replace this thing. I'm just testing some functions for ldap access to integrate it with the old base and I still need it. That's why I'm not actually making a huge effort on this. But if I can find an asp fiddle, that really would help.